# SQL aggregation with GROUP_BY where in custom field should be saved value from field 'amount' only for last created transaction item in aggregation

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, mikro-orm

I have the list of merchants, this entity is global. For certain users, I should aggregate a list of merchants by their own transactions which have relation to merchant_id, merchants should be ordered by the number of transactions for the last 3 months, and also these transactions should be not too old and exist not less than 4 transactions last 3 months. and I am stuck on the point where I have to show the last transaction amount for every merchant as well, I can't realize how to make it inside groupBy so here is my method with aggregation I sing mikrORM and NestJS:

```
async getFavorite(user: UserBriefInfoDto, pagination: PaginationDto): Promise<PaginationResponseDto<MerchantBriefDetails>> {
    try {
      const thirtyDaysAgo = moment().subtract(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const ninetyDaysAgo = moment().subtract(90, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

      const subQuery = this.transactionsRepo.createQueryBuilder('transaction')
        .select('merchant_id')
        .where({ user: { cognito_id: user.cognito_id }, posting_date: { $gte: ninetyDaysAgo } })
        .having(`COUNT(transaction) >= 4 AND MAX(transaction.posting_date) >= '${ninetyDaysAgo}'`)
        .groupBy('transaction.merchant_id'); 
/*Here is the subQuery for getting merchant_ids where users 
have enough transactions and we could move on with them */

      const favoriteTransactions: ITransactionsByMerchant[] = await this.transactionsRepo.createQueryBuilder('transaction')
        .select(`transaction.merchant_id, COUNT(transaction) as transaction_count`
/*I guess here I should make some condition that will check if the transaction
 posting_date last in our groupBy then take the transaction.amount 
field value and put in the custom field last_transaction_amount */
) 
        .leftJoin('transaction.user', 'user')
        .where({ merchant_id: { $in: subQuery.getKnexQuery() } })
        .having(`MAX(transaction.posting_date) >= '${thirtyDaysAgo}'`)
        .groupBy('transaction.merchant_id')
        .orderBy({ 'COUNT(transaction)': 'DESC' })
        .limit(pagination.pageSize, (pagination.page - 1) * pagination.pageSize)
        .execute();

      return this.getMerchantsFromAggregatedTrans(pagination, favoriteTransactions, user);
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(`get favorite merchants error: ${e.message}`);
    }
  }
```